# Struct *p != address in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct

I have a bug which I don't understand.

In this piece of code the value of p should be the address from programs:

```
static struct ProgramList{
    struct Program *program;
    struct ProgramList *next;
} programs = {NULL, NULL};

struct ProgramList *p = &programs;
```

... only it doesn't. The adress in p is 0x0097c130 and the adress of programs is 0x0097c144.

Any ideas what to do?

Edit: I'm working in Microsoft Visual Studio I'm checking the addresses with the watch function of the debugger. I am checking p and &programs.
Edit2: The address of p is 0x0040f89c. I know I'm looking for the value of p not it's address.

Comment: How are you checking those addresses?

Comment: Are you perhaps checking the _address_ of `p`?

Comment: Are you sure you're not confusing `p` with `&p`?

Comment: It is the same: [link](http://ideone.com/CNrOjN).

Comment: Please show us a minimal, compilable testcase. Minimal means "using the bare essentials to reproduce the problem", and compilable means "using enough code to reproduce the problem on our systems without guessing, filling in blanks or correcting syntax errors". We should be able to copy/paste into our editors, compile and run to reproduce your bug. We should be able to display the entire testcase on one A4 page.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Undefined behaviour. `%p` tells printf to expect a `void *`, and you're passing a `struct ProgramList *`. These two types aren't required to have the same representation. I suggest explicitly casting those arguments to `(void *)`.

Comment: @modifiablelvalue In this case, it's "six vs. half a dozen": perhaps the pointers are not required to have the same representation, yet they inevitably always do, [as if by magic](http://ideone.com/cVXuyY) :):):):)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Explain the presense of this page: http://c-faq.com/null/machexamp.html

Comment: @dasblinkenlight ... and I quote from that page: "The Eclipse MV series from Data General has three architecturally supported pointer formats (word, byte, and bit pointers), two of which are used by C compilers: byte pointers for char * and void *, and word pointers for everything else. For historical reasons during the evolution of the 32-bit MV line from the 16-bit Nova line, word pointers and byte pointers had the offset, indirection, and ring protection bits in different places in the word. Passing a mismatched pointer format to a function resulted in protection faults."

Comment: @modifiablelvalue These are the notable exceptions that prove the rule :)

Comment: I do not know were you place your breakpoints to observe the values, or where you put the `if () then` test, but I assume you do not test exactly after `p`'s assigmment, but somewhere later, so there is a good chance that the code in between `p`'s assignment and where you "measurement" corrupts the value held by `p`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight No. They're proof that, like the way a chicken runs around though it's dead, sometimes undefined behaviour seems to *work as expected*.

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  struct P *p = &programs;
  printf("%p %p %p\n", &programs, p, &p);
}
```

has this result:

bf@bf-laptop:~/playground$ ./testprogram

> 0x804a01c 0x804a01c 0xbfe32a4c

So, `&programs` and `p` are the same, but **the address** of `p` is different.

Basically, `&programs` is the address of where the struct `programs` is located. `p` is the location where the address to `programs` is stored. `&p` is the address where that address is stored.

In a schematic:

```
[address]   [name]    [value]
0x804a01c   programs  <programs struct>
0xbfe32a4c  p         0x804a01c
```

Answer (score 2):

Your method of checking the addresses is incorrect, try this:

```
struct ProgramList *p = &programs;
printf("%p %p\n", p, &programs);
```

And you should see they are the same. I suspect you're doing something like:

```
printf("%p %p\n", &p, &programs);
```

Which is the address of your pointer (not the value of it).

**EDIT**
As per your comment, you can check via that `printf` as well as long as the conditions are correct:

```
if(p == &programs)
    printf("I failed"); // will print "I failed" because the values are the same.
```

Since you said you were using VS debugger I dusted it off and stuck that code in there, looks like even in VS 2010 it's showing the same values so it's not a Microsoft trick:

[image]

Comment: I'll know it's not the address of p I'm looking for. The weird thing is that if I add this:

    if (*p == &programs)
        printf("I failed");

Doesn't print anything

Comment: @Tremnor - Same problem there you want `if(p == &programs) printf("I failed");` Note the removal of the `*` in my version

Comment: Yes sorry I didn't copy paste it from my actual code.
This is my actual code:
    if(p != &programs) printf("I failed");